# SQL not recognising table columns in ON statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, quoted-identifier

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT "Segments.Id", "AggregatedValues.Segment"
FROM "Segments"
INNER JOIN "AggregatedValues" ON "Segments.Id" = "AggregatedValues.Segment";
```

And I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  column "Segments.Id" does not exist
LINE 1: ... FROM "Segments" INNER JOIN "AggregatedValues" ON "Segments....
                                                             ^
SQL state: 42703
Character: 99
```

This is EXTREMELY weird because the column DOES EXIST. The proof is that when selecting the column in the SELECT statement, no errors are thrown. It is also weird because if I change the order and say ON "AggregatedValues.Segment" = "Segments.Id" instead of ON "Segments.Id" = "AggregatedValues.Segment" then AggregatedValues.Segment appears as non existent even tho it also exists.

Any idea? I'm going mad

Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: You should put "Segments"."Id", or even better, don't use capital letters in object names on postgresql :)

Comment: MySQL does not work with `pgadmin`, please remove the WRONG tag!

Comment: `"Segments.Id"` means a column named `Segments.Id`. You want `"Segments"."Id"`, i.e. table Segments, column Id.

Comment: @FlexYourData thanks! I knew it was some kind of thing like this. You've saved me a lot of time :)

Comment: You should [avoid](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names) those dreaded quoted identifiers to begin with.

Comment: Never ever use double quotes ". If you need them, you just shot yourself in the foot and you're waiting for the pain to arrive. Just don't use them, you don't need them.